# Android NotificationListenerService onNotificationPosted fire twice

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I listen for notifications like WhatsApp Messages.

But every time a notification comes in the NotificationListenerService fire twice.

Does anyone know this problem??

This is a snippet from the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".NotifyService"
            android:label="WhatsNotify"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And inside the NotificationListenerService class:

```
public class NotifyService extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("NotifyService", "got notification");
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
Properties of both `StatusBarNotification`s:

First notification:

`0|com.whatsapp|1|xxxxxxxxxx@s.whatsapp.net|10073`

Second notification:

`0|com.whatsapp|1|null|10073`

Comment: have you got this prob's solution

Comment: @BhanuSharma No. My solution was to create a new android project and then it worked.

Comment: means same code u wrote in new projects and it will automatically run properly?

Comment: Have u resolved this because i receive this error till date

Comment: @BhanuSharma I still don't know why I got two notifications. but I created a new project, copied the code from the class file and paste it into the new project. That worked for me.

Comment: I still got the same problem, the answer below requires API level 20, but I need it to work on level 18.

Comment: Your problem is related to group summary notifications. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55365244/1658621

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why this happens. Maybe flags of notifications could be triggering it twice.

You can try to omit duplicate executing yourself:

```
public class NotifyService extends NotificationListenerService {
    private String mPreviousNotificationKey;
    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mPreviousNotification) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(mPreviousNotification) && !sbn.getKey().equals(mPreviousNotificationKey)){
        Log.i("NotifyService", "got notification");
    }
}
```

Each `StatusBarNotification` has unique key which is generated:

```
private String key() {
   return user.getIdentifier() + "|" + pkg + "|" + id + "|" + tag + "|" + uid;

}
```

Holding each previous key can distinguish latter notification for given package.

Comment: When the notification the second time fires, all properties are the same like in the first one. Except tag. Tag is null.

Comment: @gravmatt First one has a tag? What about `key` property?

Comment: Yes it has a tag. **first time:** 0|com.whatsapp|1|xxxxxxxxxx@s.whatsapp.net|10073 **second time:** 0|com.whatsapp|1|null|10073

Comment: @gravmatt Try holding reference of the one that has tag, and execute your code when the second one arrives. I don't have any other thoughts about this.

Comment: Google  Allo application coming twice and Tag is null both time what is the answer now ? please help

Answer (score 2):

**Facing Same Problem For Whatsapp Notification**

I just solve this by generating new key with `statusBarNotification.key + statusBarNotification.title`

Now store this key in my `SQLiteDatabase`

**`code written in Kotlin`**

```
 override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
        if(sbn?.tag!=null) 
        {
        var key = sbn?.key ?: null
        var id = sbn?.id
        var postTime = sbn?.postTime
        var packageName = sbn?.packageName ?: null
        var tikerText = sbn?.notification?.tickerText ?: null

        var extraBundle: Bundle? = sbn?.notification?.extras ?: null
        var notificationTitle = extraBundle?.get(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE)
        var text = extraBundle?.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT).toString()

        var modifiyedUniq = key + notificationTitle

        //check key present in database or not
        if (!databaseHandler.checkNotification(modifiyedUniq!!)) 
         {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Key :: ${key}")
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Id :: ${id}")
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification postTime :: ${postTime}")
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification From :: ${packageName}")
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification TikerText :: ${tikerText}")
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Title :: ${notificationTitle}")
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Text :: ${text}")
            //now add this record in database
            databaseHandler.addNotification(notificationData)
         }
        }
 }
```

this method `databaseHandler.checkNotification(modifiyedUniq!!)` returns **true if record present** with this key **else it returns false**

each and every time checking the key if no record present means its **new notification**

```
fun checkNotification(key: String): Boolean {
    var isPresent: Boolean = false
    val db = readableDatabase
    val selectALLQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE $KEY='${key}'"
    val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectALLQuery, null)
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.count > 0) {
            cursor.close()
            db.close()
            Log.e("","====================================RECORD PRESEBNT=======================")
            return true
        }
    }
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    Log.e("","===*******=======********=====RECORD NOT PRESENT===*******=======********=====")
    return isPresent
}
```

Notification `0|com.whatsapp|1|XX2X606878@s.whatsapp.net|10171`

**tag = `91XX06X78@s.whatsapp.net`**

```
Notification Id :: 1
Notification postTime :: 15464X794103
Notification From :: com.whatsapp
Notification TikerText :: null
Notification Title :: XXX X Bca (2 messages): ​
Notification Text :: XXXXX(last new Message)
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me too. My workaround is to use notification's time + (notification's title + notification's text) as two keys.

If time is not older than 1 sec and similar title + text then ignore.

```
if (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - lastMessageTime < 1000 && lastMessageContent.equalsIgnoreCase(title + text)) {
        // Ignore
        return;
    } else {
        lastMessageContent = title + text;
        lastMessageTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    }
```

I worked for me but I think it may missed some notification.

Answer (score 0):

I found something, the second notification always brings null tag, so this is what I did.

```
if (sbn.tag != null) {
   // Do something
} else {
   cancelNotification(statusBarNotification.key)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by registering active notification keys like this:

```
class NotificationsListenerService : NotificationListenerService() {

    private var activeHandledNotificationKeys: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()
        
    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        if (activeHandledNotificationKeys.contains(sbn.key)) return
        
        /* Handle unique StatusBarNotification */
        
        activeHandledNotificationKeys.add(sbn.key)
    }
    
    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        activeHandledNotificationKeys.remove(sbn.key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Split you can achieve this thing.

```
 String[] separated = Your Notification key.split("\\|");
    if (!separated[3].equalsIgnoreCase("null")){//Add Your Data in list or DB }
```